# How to create a responsive design using XML android

Tags: android, xml

I am searching for the best tutorial that can explain to me step by step the basics in creating a responsive design for all screen in android studio 3 XML. I saw a lot in youtube but none of it supplements my need. I want to find a tutorial video that is step by step and direct and not too advance nor have any unrelated subjects about the topic.

Comment: Read this **[Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) and [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search about **constraint layout** because this layout is a responsive layout